# system clock keep changing

Tags: windows-7, virus, malware

I'm using Windows 7 and the system clock is almost stuck within two hours.
When I change it to the right time, the clock will stick to the right time + 2 hours (after reaching the right time + 2 hours it will go back 2 hours).
The time zone is right, so it's definitely a virus or malware; but I scanned the system using avira and kaspersky with negative results.

Is there anyway to fix it without formatting?

Comment: Malware that changes the time for giggles? Hmm, not heard of that in recent years. Even if the time zone is right, you may not have (or have wrongly) informed Windows how the hardware clock of your machine relates to the time zone you set. What's the value of `RealTimeIsUniversal` under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation`?

Comment: SE Asia Standard Time

Comment: Your comment completely disregards the request for that piece of information. Also see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/02/224672.aspx

Comment: this is the value of the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation` i didn't find the RealTimeIsUniversal key in the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a bad/rouge time server defined, which dynamically updates your system time. Please open a command prompt in administrator mode, and input this command:

```
w32tm /query /status
```

Please paste the "source" line.

It may also be possible that the time defined in your BIOS is not being set properly. When your PC powers on press DEL or F2 to enter the setup utility, and in general CMOS settings, ensure the time is set correctly there.

Comment: source: display the time source.

Comment: That's a very odd response. This line should be a server address of which is being used to receive time updates from. What does the source IP value say in above line? (line starts with ReferenceId)

Comment: sorry i run the wrong one first, but when i'm running the right one this is the result `The following error occurred: The service has not been started. (0x80070426)`

Comment: after starting the service and run the command again this is the result `Source: Local CMOS Clock`

Comment: Ah in that case you will need to enter your BIOS setup utility when your PC powers on and set the correct clock there. It's in that "Press DEL to enter setup" part when your PC powers on. Might be F2 though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed something in the Windows Services ? Have you disabled the Service **Software Licensing**?

You must do this through **safe mode**.

1. Remove all floppy disks, CDs, and DVDs from your computer, and then restart your computer.
2. Click the Start button, click the arrow next to the Lock button, and then click Restart.
3. Do one of the following:

   - If your computer has a single operating system installed, press and
     hold the F8 key as your computer restarts. You need to press <kbd>F8</kbd>
     before the Windows logo appears. If the Windows logo appears, you
     will need to try again by waiting until the Windows logon prompt
     appears, and then shutting down and restarting your computer.
   - If your computer has more than one operating system, use the arrow
     keys to highlight the operating system you want to start in safe
     mode, and then press <kbd>F8</kbd>.
   - On the Advanced Boot Options screen, use the arrow keys to highlight
     Safe Mode with command prompt, press Enter
   - Log on to your computer with a user account that has administrator rights.
   - Type services.msc in Windows Run Command
     (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
   - Then in the list of services locate Software Licensing. Right-click
     it, select Properties
   - Change “Startup type:” to Automatic, then click OK. Restart you
     computer

**Report back to us**, did it solve the problem ?

Comment: do you mean 'software protection' it was on automatic(Delay start) i change it but i can't tell now i have to wait two hours because i change the clock already in the bios.

Comment: I am not sure if it is called software protection. You must do this through safe mode.

Comment: If possible, could you please explain *how* this is supposed to help with the issue at hand?

Comment: @Bob the user reported that he gets the following error: **The following error occurred: The service has not been started (0x80070426)**
This is known to occur when the service Software Licensing is disabled (might now be called Software Protection). The above steps describe how to enable the service again.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen exactly this issue before. It was a very old installation of Windows, with (presumably) some sort of corrupted system file. Using the right time zone would cause the wrong time to be displayed. What worked for me was simply reinstalling Windows (which, incidentally fixed all the other system problems with that old installation of Windows in the process). I rarely advise jumping straight in and doing a reinstall, but having seen this myself, I think you should be open to the idea. If you do a reinstall (or repair install) you could have it fixed today- otherwise it will just drag on for a while. By the way I don't like it when people say "...blah blah blah, so it's DEFINITELY a virus or malware!". The one thing I can guarantee is that it's NOT malware. Malware is too often the scapegoat for things people can't explain IMO.

Answer (score 0):

It almost sounds like its in your BIOS.  I once had an issue like this and basically reflashed my BIOS.  That fixed my issue.  Mine wasn't quite like yours however it smells like its in your BIOS.  Have you tried installing other versions of Windows and seeing what happens to the clock?  Just something to think about.  By the way if you do end up reflashing your BIOS, there's a point where you do not want to turn off your computer.  I'm sure the upgrade software will make you aware of that though.